# Updating QGridLayouts

Tags: c++, qt

Hi guys I'm coding game for my studies and I've big problems with that (My leg was injured and I couldn't go to lessons).

My job is to do simple Battleships game in c++, qt.

I'm in point where logic code is done, but gui is a big mess.
Here's code for gui .cpp file:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog()
{
    createGraczBox();
    createKomputerBox();
    createOdpowiedz();

    QGridLayout *mainLayout = new QGridLayout;
    mainLayout->addWidget(graczBox , 0 , 0 );
    mainLayout->addWidget(komputerBox , 0 , 1 );
    mainLayout->addWidget(Odpowiedz , 0 , 2 );
    setLayout(mainLayout);

    setFixedSize(800,400);
    setWindowTitle(tr("Battleships!"));

}

void Dialog::createGraczBox()
{
    graczBox = new QGroupBox(tr("Gracz"));
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;

    for (int j = 0; j < NumGridRows; ++j) {
            labels[j] = new QLabel(tr("%0").arg(j+1));
            layout->addWidget(labels[j], 0 , j + 1 , Qt::AlignLeft);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NumGridRows; ++i) {
            labels[i] = new QLabel(tr("%0").arg(i + 1));
            layout->addWidget(labels[i], i + 1, 0);
    }

    for(int g = 1;g<10;++g)
    {
        layout->setColumnStretch(g,1);
    }
    graczBox->setLayout(layout);
}

void Dialog::createKomputerBox()
{
    komputerBox = new QGroupBox(tr("Komputer"));
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;

    for (int j = 0; j < NumGridRows; ++j) {
            labels[j] = new QLabel(tr("%0").arg(j+1));
            layout->addWidget(labels[j], 0 , j + 1 );
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NumGridRows; ++i) {
            labels[i] = new QLabel(tr("%0").arg(i + 1));
            layout->addWidget(labels[i], i + 1, 0);
    }

    for(int g = 1;g<10;++g)
    {
        layout->setColumnStretch(g,1);
    }
   komputerBox->setLayout(layout);
}

void Dialog::createOdpowiedz()
{
    Odpowiedz = new QGroupBox(tr("Komendy"));
    QFormLayout *layout = new QFormLayout;

    xLabel = new QLabel;
    QPushButton *zmienna_x_przycisk = new QPushButton(tr("X"));
    connect(zmienna_x_przycisk, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setx()));

    yLabel = new QLabel;
    QPushButton *zmienna_y_przycisk = new QPushButton(tr("Y"));
    connect(zmienna_y_przycisk, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(sety()));

    xLabel->setText(tr("Aktualne X: %1").arg(zmienna_x));
    yLabel->setText(tr("Aktualne Y: %1").arg(zmienna_y));

    layout->addRow(xLabel);
    layout->addRow(zmienna_x_przycisk);
    layout->addRow(yLabel);
    layout->addRow(zmienna_y_przycisk);
    Odpowiedz->setLayout(layout);
}

void Dialog::setx()
{
    bool ok_x;
        x = QInputDialog::getInt(this, tr("Podaj X:"),
                                     tr(""), 1, 1, 10, 1, &ok_x);
        if (ok_x)
            x=zmienna_x;
}

void Dialog::sety()
{
    bool ok_y;
        y = QInputDialog::getInt(this, tr("Podaj Y:"),
                                     tr(""), 1, 1, 10, 1, &ok_y);
        if (ok_y)
            y=zmienna_y;
}
```

They way it should work:

1. I'm choosing x and y by clicking on it.
2. Choosing numbers in new window.
3. They should appear in "Aktualne X:/Y:".
4. When I've x and y, click ok button (he's not there by now).
5. Computer checking numbers marking it in space Komputer / Gracz.
6. Reset x and y to 0.
7. Show text "You missed. Computer missed."
8. Go on till one'll win.

But I don't know how to make my layout updating itself by other actions. I can't make dowhile work here.

Comment: Maybe you want to try `QGraphScene`.

Comment: Update the layout how? You only have row numbers and column numbers inside the layout. Where are the cells that represent the actual data inside the grid?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [signals and slots here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html). Create "OK" button and `connect` it to a function, that will be used to handle your `x` and `y` variables.

Comment: I know how to add ok button, issue here is updating my whole layout.